# Pull data using VBA, Vlookup or Index Matching

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

Here is my question. I have tried to use Vlookup and receive an #NA and then I have tried to use Index Matching and the formula breaks and the returns are not all present. I receive some 0's and some #REF!'s in the column of my formula.

This is what I am trying to do. I have workbook with 2 work sheets. The first worksheet called 'brazil' is where I have written my formula in the column D. 
Now, what I am trying to do is match up the email address from worksheet 'brazil email' and the worksheet from the 'brazil' and then pull the information from the cell in the 'brazil' worksheet a column that matches with the email from the formula.

The snippet shows the formula works in row 3 column D and returns the information from column A(employee), but breaks after a few rows and works intermittently.

Current my formula looks like this: =INDEX(A2:A34, MATCH(C2, 'Brazil email'!$A$2:$A48, 0))

Here is the snippet of the other worksheet: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ5UF.png)

If you have any ideas on what could be causing the breakdown of my formula, that would be great.

I am willing to share a sample of the spreadsheet with you if needed. Thanks for any help. :)

Any other methods, like an alternate vlookup or vba would be great. :)

UPDATE 3/15:
I was able to update my formula and locked it down as per the great advice given on the below comment. :)

This is the latest update. I am still receiving #REF! on some of my cells. I copied and pasted in case there was a space and verified that the column is set to general and not text.

What could possibly be giving me the #REF! when it should be the data from the matched and index cell. I see the other rows worked but for some reason some of the cells on column D didn't update with the data from column A.

Please assist since I have 25,000 lines of this I have to sort through and trying to work smarter not harder. :)

I have removed the original snippet since the update given has corrected some of the errors. Here is the latest image with the current #REF!, Please assist: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh4al.png)

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your formula, it seems that the first parameter should be locked:

=INDEX(**$A$2:$A$34**, MATCH(C2, 'Brazil email'!$A$2:**$A$48**, 0))

When you copy your formula down, Excel will shift that first bit out of bounds.

UPDATE:

The #REF! usually comes from copying/pasting formulas or deleting/moving referenced data.

What I can think here is to make sure to put the working formula in the top cell and paste all the way down.

Also **important**: Added another lock to the formula (didn't see it before), on the referenced range inside the MATCH section.

Comment: I was able to test and found that your update did assist with resolving some of the errors. I am still seeing #REF! on some of the cells.

Comment: UPDATE 3/15: I was able to update my formula and locked it down as per the great advice given on the below comment. :)

This is the latest update. I am still receiving #REF! on some of my cells. I copied and pasted in case there was a space and verified that the column is set to general and not text.

Please review the summary.

Comment: I went ahead performed the change as you suggested and it did work. I have attached the latest picture. I am still seeing some #REF! errors on the spreadsheet. Any thoughts!

Comment: @joel , i tried to think of something other than my edit, but I'm unable to replicate the situation here (with a mock table).
Can you click and capture the formula in cell D21, the one with the #REF!?
Usually one of it's arguments will be also REF, showing where the problem lies.